# checkerboard draw behind in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

Is there a way to create a quick checkerboard pattern that can used to draw behind a shape? I can use the Rectangle Grid to make a normal grid to do this but when I create a checkerboard shape the draw behind option is grayed out. Polar Grid has an option to alternate ring color but I don't see one in Rectangle Grid. The only other way I can think of is to build the squares individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably won't get much easier than using the included checkerboard fill pattern. In CC14  you can find it within the "Decorative Legacy" swatch. Use the [scale tool](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html) to adjust the size as necessary.

[image: Checkerboard pattern in Illustrator]

Alternatively you could [make your own pattern](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/patterns.html#create_pattern_swatches).